# How can I rotate a Asset image based on obtained degrees

Tags: flutter, dart

I can get the heading of my position i.e 90 (east),82,77, 180(south) etc, I have an asset image so before I show it in the screen i want to rotate it based on the heading.

For example

```
rat = position.heading;
//here rat is 270 degrees
RotateImageFunction(
    MarkerIcon(
        image: AssetImage(
           //rotate this image 270 deg
            "images/images/arrow.png",
        ),
    ), )
```

The RotateImageFunction class

```
class RotateImageFunction{
  final String id;
  final MarkerIcon? markerIcon;
  final List<GeoPoint>? geoPoints;

  RotateImageFunction(
    this.id,
    this.markerIcon,
    this.geoPoints,
  );
}
```

The MarkerIcon class

```
class MarkerIcon extends StatelessWidget {
  final Icon? icon;
  final AssetImage? image;

  MarkerIcon({
    this.icon,
    this.image,
    Key? key,
  })  : assert(icon != null || image != null),
        super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget? child = SizedBox.shrink();
    if (icon != null) {
      child = icon;
    } else if (image != null) child = Image(image: image!);
    return child!;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by wrapping it with Transform.rotate and easily use angle to rotate it

Answer (score 0):

If you know that it will only be rotated in increments of 90 degrees, you can use `RotatedBox`:

```dart
RotatedBox(
  quarterTurns: 1,
  child: AssetImage( ... ),
)
```

If you want to be able to rotate it by any amount, you can use `Transform.rotate()`. However, you will then have to think about how the shape of your widget changes when not rotated by a multiple of 90 degrees:

```dart
Transform.rotate(
  angle: 0.5 * pi,  // radians
  child: AssetImage( ... ),
)
```

Comment: Cameron apologies, I didn't update the full code, could you please take a look again at the updated question and where exactly can I add the Transform. rotate,  I can calculate the radians as you have suggested.